# Samsung Galaxy 7" (GT-P6210) not detecting for USB debugging?

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, adt

I am using ubuntu Linux 10.04 Pc in that my **Samsung Galaxy 7"** (GT-P6210) **homeycomb 3.2** is not detecting for development its showing in eclipse as

`DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring ????????????`  in **console**

and in **device tab** its showing ?????????????.

Except this **7' GT-P6210** Samsung tablet all other Samsung devices are showing fine.

When I switch off the tablet and connected to the USB its showing the number and online as status. 
List of devices attached 
4641199B0F8488AE    device

why? whats the problem any solution.

**NOTE:**
I already Added 51-android.rules

```
Samsung 04E8
```

and also I enabled the **USB debugging** mode.

Its working fine in **Mac**.

**EDIT:** 
I got the product id thru `$ lsusb` command

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
```

I added product id in my rules.d file also

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04E8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

after that I restarted udev

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ sudo restart udev
```

then I tried

```
   padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb kill-server
    padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb start-server
    * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
    * daemon started successfully *
    padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb devices
    List of devices attached 
    ?    ???????????    offline
```

//no luck so far

I found that its not detecting in **updated ADT r16 and r15**, except all other ADT version device is detecting very fine.

and also when device is in switch off mode its showing

name 464119990CEDAB9E, status as online and the OS version 3.2 in eclipse  device tab.
and in terminal also as below.

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
464119990CEDAB9E    device
```

any idea.  Much appreciated :-)?

Comment: As discussed in this thread, I used adbWireless, and it is working well, until now... http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23708/samsung-galaxy-tab-7-plus-adb-drivers#comment28213_23708

Answer (score 5):

If, when you run `adb devices`, you see `????????????` in the list of devices, try stopping (`adb kill-server`) and restarting (`adb start-server`) the `adb` daemon.

Note that `Samsung 04E8` is not a valid entry in `51-android.rules` for `udev`. The correct line is:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
```

Also, make sure that you update the `udev` daemon after making this rules file change (`sudo restart udev`).

Comment: I am very happy to get reply from you. my 51 rules has SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev". I just copy paste this line "Samsung 04E8" from dev.and.com site. The thing is all my samsung is showing properly except this one. while connecting USB its showing MTP-Connected.

Comment: @PadmaKumar: I have never used the GROUP parameter on the rules lines, so you might consider removing that and seeing if it changes matters. Beyond that, I have no immediate suggestions.

Comment: @CommansWare I just using the lines by this http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html, but all samsung and other devices are connecting properly. The interesting thing is when I switch off the tablet and connected to the USB its showing the number and online as status. in adb devices is shows List of devices attached 4641199B0F8488AE device

Comment: I found that only its not detecting in updated ADT r16, except all other ADT version device is detecting very fine.
any idea?

Comment: @PadmaKumar: Possibly it is some regression in the tools. Consider updating your question will all your new information, then cross-posting a link to your question on http://b.android.com (assuming you cannot find an outstanding issue there that matches your symptoms).

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem.  Strangely, I can sometimes get the device to list correctly, but other times, it just won't work.  Restarting my Linux laptop resolves the issue.  What a pain!!

Today, I discovered that if I suspend my laptop, then turn it back on, it detects the device correctly again!  That really beats restarting the OS.

Comment: I am using PC. when I disconnect my usb cable and plug it again device wont detect again.

Answer (score 1):

Just stop and start adb server as root. Permissions issue will go away. Also udev step can be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, 1.Close Eclipse (IDE) first.
              2.Execute this command on terminal " adb kill-server"
              3.Now connect device to system wait, 10-20 seconds.
              4.Execute this command on terminal " adb start-server", Check device status with "adb devices " command.
              5 .Now open eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding the vendor ID in `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` would help?
Add a line with just `0x<!!!Your Vendor ID here!!!>`, then run `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`.
See this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/341696/387779.
It just saved me after nights of searching/testing/editing/pluging in and out and in again... so I thought it might be worth sharing. Thanks to Uygar Y for his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu, what I did is killing and restarting the ADB server with a sudo privilege.

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```