# direct use of adb do not recognize my tablet but eclipse did

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, adb

I can run my app from eclipse
but when i try to use adb directly form terminal

it says

> adb server is out of date.  killing...

after it restart the deamon, my tablet is not listed

it works fine for almost a year until today
have no idea what happen.

### more information

- Tablet: ASUS Transformer TF01
- ADT plugin updated
- android SDK Tools updated
- result of "adb devices" shows there is no devices attached. (not even ?????????)
- another android device HTC Desire HD works but "adb server is out of date.  killing..." occurs
- recent change: updated TF01 firmware two days ago, use aahk tools to root my Desire HD yesterday

Comment: which tablet? Did you updated your ADT?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668923/samsung-galaxy-7-gt-p6210-not-detecting-for-usb-debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solve by remove the executable

> /bin/adb

and make a softlink link to adb in platform-tools

> sudo ln -s /sdk/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/adb adb