# ADB suddenly doesn't detect my device anymore

Tags: android, linux, adb

[update 1] During the below attempts to make this thing work, I rebooted several times.  However this morning I turn on my computer and now the device is listed...  However I will keep my question open for a few days to see if this odd behavior comes back.[/update 1]

`adb` under Arch Linux (32bits) suddenly stopped reporting my phone, which it usually does.  I tried all the following commands both as sudo and normal user, with the same lack of result.

```
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo gvim /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

In which I wrote:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTR{idProduct}=="0ccf", MODE="0666", OWNER="antoine"
```

Then I did:

```
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

The device was there:

```
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0bb4:0ccf High Tech Computer Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:0a15 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Wireless Mouse M305
```

So I killed the `adb server`

```
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo adb kill-server
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

Yet it didn't work:

```
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo adb devices
List of devices attached 

[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$
```

Then I tried to update `adb` with :

```
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo android update adb
adb has been updated. You must restart adb with the following commands
    adb kill-server
    adb start-server
```

Then modified the `adb_usb.ini` file (both in root and in ~):

```
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo gvim /root/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

I wrote:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x0bb4
```

Then :

```
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo adb kill-server
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$ sudo adb devices
List of devices attached 

[antoine@amadeus /home/antoine/]$
```

This whole thing was working just fine yesterday and the day before and so on.  I have not updated my system nor anything since then.  I am puzzled.

Comment: I ended up using ADB WIFI after my cable connector stopped working. The only downside is that both the computer and the device need to be connected to the same network, other than that it works just fine. MAYBE, this helps you, that's why its not an answer and just a comment.I believe you need to be rooted for this (more than likely), the app is free and has no ads that I'm aware of, here's a link  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.adbw&hl=en

Comment: try sudo restart udev before adb kill-server.

Comment: check will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8668923/1012284

Comment: For reference: I noticed that sometime, unplugging/plugging, refreshing drivers, revising manifest for restriction, switching debug mode, etc, doesn't work, but refreshing available devices solves it.

Comment: I had the same problem, adb suddenly stopped working, and I realised it was because I had a VM running that was stealing the USB device. Turned off the VM, adb was working again!

Answer (score 5):

OK, I had this exact same problem with a Samsung Galaxy Mini, and my setup is an Ubuntu box running oneiric.

I had not touched the laptop before this stopped working so I was pretty sure the configuration on the laptop was sound. The only thing I've done (before this started happening) was install 2 apps from Google Play on the device. A Messenger Client and some other app which I really do not recall the name nor what it was for.

For some reason, which I have not yet figured out, my laptop stopped being able to detect the galaxy mini for debugging purposes. I tried all tricks described here (several changes to udev confs, checking adb confs , killing/stopping/restarting everything with different orders) and only one thing got the device to get detected again and it was :

Reseting the phone.

Not elegant but it was the only thing that got my galaxy mini to get detected again by ADB.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but this did not help.

Answer (score 3):

Please ensure that on your phone you have checked:

Settings -> Developer options -> USB debugging

Answer (score 1):

When using a ROM like "Cyanogenmod 10.2 (Android 4.3)" you need to do the following...

1. Go into Settings...
2. Find "About phone" then click it.
3. Scroll down to "Build number" and click it like 10 times in a row until it says "developement settings enabled".
4. Go back a page to the "Settings" screen and go into "Developer options".
5. Ensure "USB debugging" is ticked.
6. Open "task manager" on the PC and kill "adb.exe"
7. Restart phone.
8. Once phone has booted up completely to the OS run "adb devices".

Another trick...

1. At your home screen in the OS hold the down volume button and press the power button.
2. Do this until you see the screen go black and the lights at the bottom flash.
3. Let go of all buttons and try the "adb devices" command again.
4. Should be able to run your adb commands now. (such as "adb reboot bootloader")

Answer (score 1):

Same problem observed on ubuntu, I tried the following and it worked:

Reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918512

Use the command `udevadm` from the above reference for example:

```
"sudo udevadm test --action="SUBSYSTEM=="usb", 
ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="[vendor_id]", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="[model_id]" MODE="0666", 
SYMLINK+="[Device_Name]"" $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/bus/usb/001/[DevNum])"
```

This seems to fix some link files and that solved the problem of adb not detecting device after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with LG Q6 device and Windows host. This was caused by switching the phone's USB mode from "Charging" to "File transfer". Reverting this change fixed the issue - ADB listed this device again.

Answer (score -1):

AntoineG，

I get into the same trouble as you said --- adb driver is properly installed and usb debugging options is turned on, the phone's adb Interface is listed in the Device Manager (My android phone's storage also can be displayed in my windows Explorer), however, I type "adb devices" no devices are listed. I get into this trouble suddenly as you said, I can use USB connection yesterday morning, but the adb can't detect my device yesterday afternoon... that's very strange, I try to connect my phone to another computer to see if there is something wrong with my phone, failed, I try to connect other phones to my computer, succeed, I guess that there was something wrong with my phone and then I reset the phone and try to reconnect it to the computer, failed again.

Then, I try to add the vendor ID in adb_usb.ini, my OS is Windows 7, it's location is %userprofile%.android\adb_usb.ini, my device's vendor ID is not listed on Google's Vender ID list.

and try the following commands in cmd

adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices

it detected a devices but the status is offline, unplug and replug the usb cable and type adb devices
everything is normal as before

I don't know why the adb suddenly cannot detect the device, maybe someone can explain that?

Comment: Please notice that this question is tagged Linux.