# Trouble Connecting Azpen Tablet to Linux PC

Tags: android

I purchased a new tablet which is manufactured by a company called Azpen.  The product page for the device is http://www.azpenpc.com/product_t64.html  I'm trying to develop apps for it and I'm a beginner. I connected the device to my Linux machine (running CentOS 5.3) but something isn't working right. I can't install the simple HelloWorld program via 'ant debug install'. Here's the output of some adb commands, which I ran as a regular user, then as root:

```
# adb usb
error: insufficient permissions for device
# adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I did 'adb kill-server ; adb start-server' as root, but this didn't help.

Does anyone know what the problems is?  My next attempt at debugging this myself was to create a new rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d, but I don't know what 'idVendor' to use for Azpen devices. Can anyone help with this?

ps. I also posted this on http://forums.androidcentral.com

Comment: try like this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8668923/1012284

Comment: post as answer that worked for U.

Comment: @JB_User Would you please elaborate me, How to do this? I am struggling with connecting my AZPEN tablet to my linux. I can connect other devices as well. But AZPEN is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran 'dmesg' and grepped for 'idVendor' in the output and found:

```
usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=0003
```

So I added this line to /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

then restarted adb as root: 'adb kill-server ; adb start-server' and it worked.