# Connect USB debugging in AZPEN tablet

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707400/solved-trouble-connecting-azpen-tablet-to-linux-pc) to connect my tablet with my `LINUX` machine for USB debugging. It was not working for me. I can able to connect other devices such as `CANVAS HD` and `SAMSUNG smart phones`.When trying to connect the [AZPEN](http://www.azpenpc.com/product_t81.html) tablet, No devices are found.

[image: Check the snap shot here.]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Reth, same thing for me. I have the A720/721 model and I can not connect with the Andriod sdk with Unbuntu. I don't get errors or question marks like the article you referenced. I also tried Win7 with the usb drivers from their website.. same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had requested to the manufacturer of `AZPEN` tablet regarding this issue, they told that, there is `no such facility available` in Azpen tablet. Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: so there is no way of using this tablet with ADT or developing android apps and deploying them to the tablet..?

Comment: @Randolphg, There is no way to debug directly. You can only send apk thro' mail and then you can test. No other way i believe.

Comment: I guess you get what you pay for. I purchased it for $20 hoping to get a cheap development device. I will use the method which you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with my **Azpen A1048** running Lollipop versus Android Studio on Windows 7.  I enabled USB debugging on the Azpen, but `adb` on Windows could not see it.  Also, though I could mount it via USB and transfer files, the Azpen never showed up in Windows' *Devices and Printers* screen.

The tablet did appear under Windows' *Device Manager* as **A1048**, but reinstalling Windows' driver for it gave no success with adb.  Meanwhile another device  called *HP 7 G2* seemed to come and go with the Azpen.  I initially dismissed it as a phantom but finally used it to make adb work with the Azpen!  Here's how:

1. Install [USB Driver Tool](http://visualgdb.com/UsbDriverTool/) *;
2. Run `UsbDriverTool.exe` as administrator;
3. Right click on the *HP 7 G2* device;
4. Select *Install Android ADB Driver* from the popup menu;
5. Restart `adb` from a command prompt using `adb kill-server` then `adb devices -l`.

Here is the resulting output from adb:

```
List of devices attached
033818f698d500000000   device product:astar_h7 model:A1048 device:astar-h7
```

Also the tablet now appears in Windows' *Devices and Printers* and *Eject* screens as "MTP".

I'm guessing the identifier disparities are a slip on Azpen's part, but at least I can deploy to the Azpen directly from Android Studio now.

*I'm not certain [USB Driver Tool](http://visualgdb.com/UsbDriverTool/) was a requirement; it's just how I happened to fix this problem.