# Samsung devices not showing up on Ubuntu 12.04 lsusb nor adb

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile, lsusb

I've a Ubuntu 12.04 PC, and for some reason today it stopped detecting my 2 Samsung devices (a Galaxy S3 and a Galaxy Note2 LTE). Neither lsusb nor adb detects them. It still detects my Nexus 5 though.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8668923/1012284