# Ubuntu is not detecting my android device

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I am new to android. I have just downloaded and installed android sdk. Now when I run the application from  eclipse, my device is not getting detected. I have googled and was brought up with this as my solution, but that also didn't worked.

Here's the 51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTR{idProduct}=="0bb4",  ATTR{idProduct}=="0c03", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugindev", OWNER="<username>"
```

After that I rebooted my laptop, and ran this command:

```
username@laptopname:~/Android/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools$ adb devices
```

The output i get is:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

**EDIT**

If i run `lsusb`, i get the following output when the device is pluged in.

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bb4:0c03 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b337 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am using Micromax Canvas 2.2 A114 - Android Version 4.2.2

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/8668923/1012284

Answer (score 5):

please follow the step
open command promt
I have write blog for detecting phone in Ubuntu kindle check [this](https://androidteachers.com/android/android-development-with-ubuntu-ubuntu-is-not-detecting-my-android-device/)
1) Enter command

```
gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules
```

2)Enter password and enter below rules inside

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e79", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666"
```

3) save and enjoy...

This is work for me and if not then let me inform 
i have post this answer related to 70 rules structure.

Thanx...

for 51-android.rules check out [this](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules/blob/master/51-android.rules) and [this](http://www.janosgyerik.com/adding-udev-rules-for-usb-debugging-android-devices/).

Comment: do i need to write everything ? or just the coded part : `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"` ?

Comment: just copy and paste .

Comment: let me know i will make changes.

Comment: @Imtiyaz deepGami is IOS developer when you posted your answer with in a minute he said "its work for me" is he is your colleague?

Comment: okay try command "gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules"
and add above rules inside it save it close it back to terminal press "control+c" and exit the terminal and check is it working or not.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you switched on the developer option in your device .
If not go to settings and select developer option and tick USB debugging

Comment: are you getting Target as unknown , state as ??  ?

Comment: checkout answer given by Imtiyaz

Answer (score 2):

//try this in cmd

```
$ lsusb
```

this will list out the details of pluged USB device details

like if you had a HTC One connected you would get:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bb4:0c02
```

then you need to do

```
Add to the file (or create it if it does not exist- see above) /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules the following line:

SUBSYSTEMS==”usb”, ATTRS{idVendor}==”0bb4″, ATTRS{idProduct}==”0c02″, MODE=”0666″
```

**Note:** so for you Micromax `vendor id` is **not 0bb4**

Finally if its not connected
try this one

Under Linux there is also an adb_usb.ini from the SDK where you have to add the vendor IDs:

```
~/.android/adb_usb.ini

# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x2080
0x04e8
```

// restart udev

```
$ sudo restart udev
```

Check if the device is recognized:

```
$ adb devices
```

You may need to stop and start the adb server:

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```

Comment: check the question now.

Comment: where can i find `/.android/adb_usb.ini` file ? I mean the directory. Is it in `platform-tools` or in `tools` ?

Comment: thats hidden in you home dir. press ctrl+h to view that.

Answer (score 0):

1.You should replace `<username>` by 'your username'.
2.In debugging options in your phone, you should toggle `USB Debugging` on.
3.When you plug your device in computer, you should allow this computer(it will jump out a dialog that ask for your permission, just press 'OK').

Comment: Not a single pop up is shown when i plug in the usb cable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're supposed to restart ADB.

Just use this steps:

1. start command prompt Press **ctrl+alt+T**
2. write Step 1:-  `adb kill-server`  and press enter.
3. write Step 2:-  `sudo adb start-server`  and press enter.
4. Now you can enjoy Debugging in Eclipse with real Android phone on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

My computer 1 don't recognize my android device.

I plug my android on computer 2 which recognize my android.

I plug my android on computer 1 which recognize my android.